Major church father / reformer who thought Paul is one of the 24 elders in Rev 4:4 and/or one of the 12 apostles of the Lamb in Rev 21:14
Before Pentecost, as recorded in Acts 1:12-26, the 11 apostles cast lot between 2 men

... who have been with [them] the whole time the Lord Jesus was living among [them] beginning from John's baptism to the time when Jesus was taken up from us.  For one of these must become a witness with us of his resurrection.  (Acts 1:21-22)

and Matthias was chosen.
One interpretation for Rev 4:4 about the identity of the 24 elders is that twelve will be the 12 OT patriarchs while the other twelve will be the 12 apostles.
Will Matthias be the 12th one in either of the 2 scenes in Revelation (Rev 4:4 and Rev 21:14), or will Paul be the 12th one since Jesus himself (rather than humans by lots, despite that they are acting as apostles) seems to commission him as "apostle" (Acts 9:15)?  Or was Paul's "title" only an "instrument" (skeuos), despite that Paul called himself "apostle of Christ Jesus by the will of God" (1 Cor 1:1, apostolos)?
It seems the interpretation is a matter of opinion, and a previous question was closed for that reason.
So instead, I'm asking this historical question: were there a major church father or a reformer who explicitly named Paul as one of the 24 elders in Rev 4:4 and/or one of the 12 apostles of the Lamb in Rev 21:14?  This also requires the 24 / the 12 to be interpreted literally rather than symbolically.  Please provide a quote.

I don't think we're meant to try to identify exactly who they are. See my answer to this Hermeneutics question. But no doubt the church fathers/reformers had their own opinions... they did on every other topic!

@curiousdannii I see.  So this may not be as interesting a question as I thought before.  Would it be okay to let it stand just to see what turns up, for historical curiosity sake?

Yeah the question is okay, but I'd be extremely surprised if no one thought Paul was one of them. That's almost a given.

The Bible speaks of "the twelve" and of "the eleven".
The eleven are referenced at Acts 1:13 as they gathered in the upper room after Christ's ascension.  There, with a group of about 150 believers, Peter determines a prophecy from the OT that Judas' position should be refilled, but by whom?

And they prayed, and said, Thou, Lord, which knowest the hearts of all men, shew whether of these two thou hast chosen, That he may take part of this ministry and apostleship, from which Judas by transgression fell, that he might go to his own place. And they gave forth their lots; and the lot fell upon Matthias; and he was numbered with the eleven apostles. Acts 1:24-26

Casting lots was a well-established method of making the right decision within an uncertain choice (see Lev 16:8, Jos 18:10, Jon 1:7).
Matthias was chosen.  Tradition says he was one of the Seventy and thus fulfilled the requirement of eyewitness from baptism to ascension.  And, for what it's worth, he's not not mentioned subsequently.  See here and here.
As well, Irenaeus follows the same thinking.

while Matthias was ordained in his place, according to what is written, “And his bishopric let another take. AH, Book II, Chapter XX, P2

And then there's Clement of Alexandria with the same thought.

But they were capable of becoming apostles on being chosen by Him who foresees even ultimate issues. Matthias, accordingly, who was not chosen along with them, on showing himself worthy of becoming an apostle, is substituted for Judas. Stomata, Book 6, Chapter XIII, P1

In paragraph 2 of the same book, Clement sees the 24 seats of Revelation 4:4 pretty widely.

Those, then, also now, who have exercised themselves in the Lord’s commandments, and lived perfectly and gnostically according to the Gospel, may be enrolled in the chosen body of the apostles. Such an one is in reality a presbyter of the Church, and a true minister (deacon) of the will of God, if he do and teach what is the Lord’s; not as being ordained3380 by men, nor regarded righteous because a presbyter, but enrolled in the presbyterate3381 because righteous.  And although here upon earth he be not honoured with the chief seat,3382 he will sit down on the four-and-twenty thrones,3383 judging the people, as John says in the Apocalypse. IBID

Tertullian is even more clear.

Accordingly, after one of these had been struck off, He commanded the eleven others, on His departure to the Father, to “go and teach all nations, who were to be baptized into the Father, and into the Son, and into the Holy Ghost.”2052 Immediately, therefore, so did the apostles, whom this designation indicates as “the sent.” Having, on the authority of a prophecy, which occurs in a psalm of David,2053 chosen Matthias by lot as the twelfth, into the place of Judas, they obtained the promised power of the Holy Ghost for the gift of miracles and of utterance; and after first bearing witness to the faith in Jesus Christ throughout Judæa, and founding churches (there), they next went forth into the world and preached the same doctrine of the same faith to the nations. Prescription Against Heretics, Chapter XX

Lastly, there's Origen.

was enabled to behold, and along with him the twelve (Matthias having been substituted in room of Judas) Against Celsus, Book II, Chapter LXV

So, it is fairly clear that early tradition saw Matthias as one of the twelve.
What about Paul, the apostle to the Gentiles?
Hippolytus mentions Paul was chosen into the apostleship, but not as part of the twelve.


And Matthias, who was one of the seventy, was numbered along with the eleven apostles, and preached in Jerusalem, and fell asleep and was buried there.




And Paul entered into the apostleship a year after the assumption of Christ; and beginning at Jerusalem, he advanced as far as Illyricum, and Italy, and Spain, preaching the Gospel for five-and-thirty years. And in the time of Nero he was beheaded at Rome, and was buried there.  Hippolytus on the 12 apostles


And the weighty Jerome says this.

Paul,2355 formerly called Saul, an apostle outside the number of the twelve apostles, was of the tribe of Benjamin and the town of Giscalis2356 in Judea.  Lives of Illustrious Men, Chapter V

To answer the OP, there does not to be any early church father who sees Paul as one of The Twelve.  They all (the ones quoted) all understand Matthias to be of The Twelve.  Paul was clearly an apostle, a messenger sent, just as the 12 were with signs and wonders.  So, there is not a positive answer that the elders of Revelation 4:4 and Revelation 21:14 were The Twelve including Paul, but rather Matthias.
EDIT TO ADD
Victorinus sees the 24 of Revelation 4:4 as 12 angels of day and 12 angels of night.

The day, as I have above related, is divided into two parts by the number twelve—by the twelve hours of day and night; and by these hours too, months, and years, and seasons, and ages are computed. Therefore, doubtless, there are appointed also twelve angels of the day and twelve angels of the night, in accordance, to wit, with the number of hours. For these are the twenty-four witnesses of the days and nights2241 which sit before the throne of God, having golden crowns on their heads, whom the Apocalypse of John the apostle and evangelist calls elders, for the reason that they are older both than the other angels and than men.  On the Creation of the World


Christ Himself is the true foundation: the twelve are foundations only in regard to their apostolic testimony concerning Him. Though Paul was an apostle besides the twelve, yet the mystical number is retained, twelve representing the Church, namely thirty the divine number, multiplied by four, the world number. Jamieson Fausset Brown


Was there a major Church Father or Reformer who thought that St. Paul is one of the 24 elders in Rev 4:4 and/or one of the 12 apostles of the Lamb in Rev 21:14?
The short answer would seem to be no. But that would not seem to rule out that very possibly. In fact, I would be surprised that any Church Father or Reformer would actually deny this to be a possibility.
Although St. Paul is an Apostle, no one would doubt the possibility that he would be numbered amongst the 12 Apostles of Revelation 4:4 or the 24 Elders of Revelation 21:14.
Although the 12 Apostles or the 24 Elders are not named in the Book of Revelation, or in Christian tradition, the four (4) living creatures of the Apocalypse are traditionally symbolized as being the 4 Evangelists.

4Surrounding the throne were twenty-four other thrones, and seated on them were twenty-four elders. They were dressed in white and had crowns of gold on their heads.
7In the center, around the throne, were four living creatures, and they were covered with eyes, in front and in back. 7 The first living creature was like a lion, the second was like an ox, the third had a face like a man, the fourth was like a flying eagle. 8 Each of the four living creatures had six wings and was covered with eyes all around, even under its wings. Day and night they never stop saying:
“‘Holy, holy, holy is the Lord God Almighty,’ who was, and is, and is to come.”
Revelation 4:4 & 7-8

Since the second century the four living creatures of the Apocalypse were thought to be or at least symbolize the Four Evangelists.
This connection was made by some Church Fathers as early as St. Irenaeus (d. 202). Here's a table showing the views of several fathers whose writings we have on this subject:

Lion Ox Man Eagle

Irenaeus (d. 202): John Luke Matthew Mark

Victorinus (d. 303): Mark Luke Matthew John

Jerome (d. 420): Mark Luke Matthew John

Augustine (d. 430): Matthew Luke Mark John



The living creature like to a lion designates Mark, in whom is heard the voice of the lion roaring in the desert. And in the figure of a man, Matthew strives to declare to us the genealogy of Mary, from whom Christ took flesh. [...] Luke, in narrating the priesthood of Zacharias as he offers a sacrifice for the people, and the angel that appears to him with respect of the priesthood, and the victim in the same description bore the likeness of a calf. John the evangelist, like to an eagle hastening on uplifted wings to greater heights, argues about the Word of God. (Commentary on the Apocalypse)

Either the Apostles St. John and St. Matthew are figured twice in the fourth chapter of Revelation or their being two of the living creatures in Revelation 4, leaving two spots vacant amongst the 12 apostles to be filled by the Apostles St. Matthias and St. Paul.
Other traditional interpretations do exist. See: The four living creatures and twenty-four elders in Revelation?
In any case St. Paul is not explicitly named as being one of the 12 Apostles of Revelation 4:4 or the 24 Elders in Revelation 21:14 by any Church Father or Reformer.

Well earlier in acts they instructed to not do anything before they receive the Holy Spirit , and Peter being Peter cast lots to choose who would fill Judas’s spot , Then after made that decision they received the Holy Spirit. Later on in acts Jesus revealed himself to Paul , so I have always took this as ( Mathias was man’s attempt to choose an apostle but Paul was anointed by the Holy Spirit.

Welcome to C.SE.  To learn how this site works, please take the tour.  Yes, your position on Paul's apostleship is shared by many, but you haven't answered the question.  In this site, answers have to address the question asked, otherwise they can be deleted.
